# Where focus should be set if HTML element removed?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, focus, accessibility, screen-readers

I have HTML (simplified) like this:

```
<ul>
  <li><a id="1" onclick="removeItself(1)" href="#">first</a></li>
  <li><a id="2" onclick="removeItself(2)" href="#">second</a></li>
</ul>
<input type="text"></input>
```

If the one of the links is clicked it will be removed. In my case after removing, the whole list will be rendered again.

There are many questions, but the general is where to set focus if element with focus is removed?

Where should be focus set if e.g. the second list element is removed or if all elements are removed?

What solution is web-accessible in this case? Is it acceptable to set focus always on the first item in the list, but if all items are removed to set focus to the next (input) or to a previous element?

In IE the focus will be reset and it will start from the beginning of the page.

Answer (score 3):

The general principle I would apply here is:

1. if a next element exists, place the focus on the next element,
2. otherwise, if a previous element exists, place it on the previous element,
3. otherwise, place it on some element before or after that makes sense, of there is none, then do nothing

Here is the Angular.js TodoMVC application that I have modified to behave this way (although you could argue that I have not done a good enough job on #3 from above)

http://dylanb.github.io/todomvc/index.html#/

Here is a blog post on the process of making the delete work

http://unobfuscated.blogspot.com/2015/02/angularjs-accessibility-deleting-todo.html

Comment: Unfortunately, the links are dead.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did based on the [answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/99411) for question [Where to put focus after deleting an item in a list](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/99344/where-to-put-focus-after-deleting-an-item-in-a-list)

> Following the principle of Least Surprise, I would leave the space open with "[deleted]" in it til the cursor moves off the list, at which point the gap can be closed.

##### Given:

Say there are 3 items in a list and user uses up / down arrow to navigate and **focuses on the second one**.

##### User Action:

There is a **delete** button inside the list item, user tabs onto it and presses enter.

##### Context Feedback:

After deletion succeeded, focus will be placed on **an invisible item** at the original place where the second item was, and this invisible item contains text "Deleted" (screen reader will **announce "Deleted"**).

##### Clean Up:

Then user can still use up / down to **move focus** to the previous / next item (or what you implemented before), and invisible item would be **removed after onblur** event triggered.